# How to keep a user signed in using Shared Preferences

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, sharedpreferences

I have a scanning app that uses Firebase for Authorisation, I used Shared Preferences to keep the user signed in after closing the app but I get an error that says,

`The getter 'uid' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: uid`

Below is my Main.dart page

In this main block, there is a ternary condition that is supposed to determine which page to go to based on wether the app was just closed or signed out

```
Future <void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 var email = preferences.get("email");
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Jinjer Pay",
      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.amber,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: email != null ? Login() : Scan_QR()));
     // home: Login()));
}
```

Code for Login Page
I put the shared preferences block at the end of the Auth. block.
I am not sure if I have initialised the shared preferences block correctly with the Auth block.

```
 RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Log In",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                                  ),
                                  color: Colors.amberAccent,
                                  elevation: 10,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                      Loading();
                                      formKey.currentState.save();

                                      setState(() => loading = true);

                                      try {
                                        UserCredential res;
                                        String userID;

                                        res = (await FirebaseAuth.instance
                                            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                            email:
                                            _emailController.text,
                                            password:
                                            _passwordController
                                                .text));
                                        userID = res.user.uid;


                                        if (res != null) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            loading = false;
                                          });
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                          Navigator.of(context).push(
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (context) =>
                                                    Scan_QR()),
                                          );
                                        }
                                      } catch (e) {
                                        if (FirebaseAuth
                                            .instance.currentUser.uid !=
                                            e.code) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            loading = false;
                                          });
                                        }

                                        if (e.code == "unknown") {
                                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                              msg:
                                              "Email/Password Field cannot be Empty",
                                              toastLength:
                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                              backgroundColor:
                                              Colors.redAccent,
                                              textColor: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 16.0);
                                        }
                                        if (e.code == "wrong-password") {
                                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                              msg:
                                              "Your password is incorrect",
                                              toastLength:
                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                              backgroundColor:
                                              Colors.redAccent,
                                              textColor: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 16.0);
                                        }
                                        if (e.code == "invalid-email") {
                                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                              msg:
                                              "Email/Password Field cannot be Empty",
                                              toastLength:
                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                              backgroundColor:
                                              Colors.redAccent,
                                              textColor: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 16.0);
                                        }
                                        if (e.code == "user-not-found") {
                                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                              msg:
                                              "No User found with this email",
                                              toastLength:
                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                              backgroundColor:
                                              Colors.redAccent,
                                              textColor: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 16.0);
                                        }
                                        if (e.code == "user-disabled") {
                                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                              msg:
                                              "user with this email has been disabled",
                                              toastLength:
                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                              backgroundColor:
                                              Colors.redAccent,
                                              textColor: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 16.0);
                                        }
                                        if (e.code ==
                                            "network-request-failed") {
                                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                              msg:
                                              "A network error has occurred",
                                              toastLength:
                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                              backgroundColor:
                                              Colors.redAccent,
                                              textColor: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 16.0);
                                        }
                                        if (e.code == "too-many-requests") {
                                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                              msg:
                                              "Too many requests, try again later",
                                              toastLength:
                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                              backgroundColor:
                                              Colors.redAccent,
                                              textColor: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 16.0);
                                        }

                                         SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                         preferences.setString("email", _emailController.text);
                                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) =>
                                                  Scan_QR()),
                                        );
                                        
                                        print(e);
                                       
                                        _passwordController.text = "";
                                      }

                                      
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
```

I have a Sign Out Block that is supposed to sign out the previously signed-in user data from the app and wait for a new user to sign in.

```
Future<void> SignOut() async {
     SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     preferences.remove("email");

   await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) => Navigator.of(context)
       .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login())));

  }
```

Comment: Hello, is this a web app or a mobile app?

Comment: It is a Mobile App

Comment: In that case you do not need to use SharedPreferences. By default the firebase_auth package keeps the user signed in. If your user signs in, closes the app, and then opens it again they will remain signed in, you do not need to implement this functionality manually.

Comment: As others have said: Firebase already keeps the user signed in. It's just that this requires it to call to the server, which means it may take some time and happens asynchronously. Check the FlutterFire documentation for how to pick up auth state changes: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state

Answer (score 1):

You could use `StreamBuilder` to check the authentication process when open the app instead of using the shared preference.

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
        stream: mAuth.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;
            if (user == null) {
              //add the logic when user is null
            } else {
              // add the logic when user is not null
            }
            
          } else {
            // add the logic when connection state not active
          }
        },
    );
  }
```

Then you could do your authentication process without using the shared preference.

Hope this answer will solve your problem!

Comment: I add the Stream builder on the Login Page?

Comment: Not for the login page. You have to add streambuilder when you check the authentication process while opening the app.